# How i could replace a string by incremental value using a block in groovy?

Tags: groovy, replace, lambda

I'm trying to learn how I could use groovy I know ruby

and I use this code for replace a string by incremental value

```
 o=0
puts "n,n,n,n,n,n,n,n".gsub(/n/) { o+=1; "#{o}"  }
```

for obtain this **1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8**

How I could do this in groovy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it almost the same:

```
def o=0
println 'n,n,n,n,n,n,n,n'.replaceAll(/n/) { ++o }
```

If you just want 8 consecutive comma-separated numbers you can also simply do

```
println((1..8).join(','))
```